# Repair/Rebuild NiMh battery pack?

Tags: nimh

2 years ago, bought a name brand cordless VSR drill motor with a 12 V battery pack for only $20.
(I realize now, it was on clearance, as Manufacturer moved to a line of 20 V interchangeables...so it had been on shelf a while.)

Been happy, but now it's not putting out much work before dieing.

Checked charger module that came with it (it looks like a regular AC/DC converter, with a 90 plug going to handle, so you won't try to use it plugged in).

1. Charger label says output is 24V DC 1 amp: is that too much?
2. I put multimeter to it: read 30 V, is THAT too much?
   (Is that a bad reading if the 9V in the multimeter is a little low?)

There is no indicator light on this model charger, or product, so I tended to leave it plugged in a lot, since, when I left it UN-plugged, it would go half dead, or all dead, after a week or so...

3. was this 'over-charging' and bad for it?

The battery is ten NiMh cells,  1.2 V - 1000 mAh:

4. Will it damage the drill motor and/or circuits in it, to put a 18v, or 24 V pack on it? (IDK if the connector/latch would even be compatible...)
5. I have read about people 'jump starting' cells that go into a charging station (usually in pairs, I guess); is this something I can do to the cells in this battery?  (I opened the case, and all the tabs' welds are intact; I tested cells, some show over 1.1 V, but a couple show like 0.1 V.)

Can those cells be jumped to facilitate charging?

At this point, the battery pretty useless, and cost of repair is almost more than getting a whole new deal...

Thank you!

Comment: You're probably going to be better off sourcing new 1000maH cells and replacing the dead ones.  If the power supply is giving 24V, then there should be a proper battery charger circuit in the drill or battery pack.

Comment: If the charge current is low enough, voltage can be almost as high as it wants without damaging the NiMH batteries. In practice, this makes for a slow and inefficient charger, but cheap to make. Get yourself a new pack or a spot welder and make a new (or replace the bad cells).

Comment: Thank you Simon, and winny!  Any idea what a tiny spot-welder costs!